# Confusion regarding intuition about homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider the following picture:

[image]

Here the black line $B$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb S^1$, whereas a space that is black and green lines together $BG$ is homotopy equivalent to $\Bbb S^1 \vee \Bbb S^1$, so that $B$ and $BG$ have different fundamental groups and are not homotopy equivalent.

Yet, if we consider them as loops something different happens. That is, $B$ corresponds to $f_1\cdot f_2$ and $BG$ is $f_1\cdot \bar g \cdot g\cdot f_2$, but these two paths happen to be homotopic. What am I missing here?

Well, ok - maybe one can say that I should think that when going by $g$ forward and backward I kinda eliminate $g$ from the picture, but that does not seem to help to resolve the following situation. On the pictures below $f$ and $f_1\cdot f_2$ are path homotopic, and yet the corresponding spaces are not homotopy equivalent, and here we do not go the same path forward and backward anywhere. So how to understand what is the connection between the homotopy equivalence of topological spaces and paths they correspond to?

P.S. If someone could help me making those pics smaller, I'd greatly appreciate it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Just because some two paths are homotopic doesn't mean spaces are homotopic. Perhaps you confuse a path with its image?

Comment: Why can't the sum of two loops be another loop? If $g_1,g_2$ are the two loops involving the green segment, and $b$ is the black loop, all you've show is $g_1g_2=b$ in the fundamental group.

Comment: Also, in your second paragraph: what exactly are those non-homotopic spaces? Complements of the union of black circle and grey path? Yes, some spaces can be homotopic, while they complements are not. Finally, spaces do not correspond to any path. Generally spaces are not an image of a path, those that are are known as Peano spaces (compact, connected, locally connected, second countable).

Comment: @freakish can you specify, what do you refer to by my second paragraph? Say, what are the first words. Regarding your first question, I definitely thought of paths as their images with maybe induced orientation. To me homotopy of the paths and of their images seemed to be equivalent, which definitely worked in some situations - but also seems to be an intuition promoted in the book of Hatcher I use to study algebraic topology now. Well, if not promoted, it is definitely how pictures show it there and nowhere it is said that one should be cautious and not confuse between those two notions

Comment: ...unless I missed it of course. Definitely, one can say that no one has explicitly suggested that those two notions are equivalent, but so far AT seems to use a lot of pictures to build up a geometric intuition (before algebraic formality starts supporting it), and apparently some of those picture may be confusing. At least to me. That's why I've asked for the help here :)

Comment: @Ilya so I strongly suggest you get rid of that intuition. **Paths are not their images**. You run into lots of problems with that intuition. For example $f\cdot \overline{f}$ is always homotopic to a point, regardless of what its image is (which is equal to $f$ image). But clearly not every image of a path is contractible, e.g. $S^1$. Also note that some paths are crazy, e.g. [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve). In fact every sphere $S^n$ is an image of a path. How do you orient such path?

Comment: @Ilya as for the second paragraph. I meant your second drawing. What is the "corresponding space"? We have a black path, and a grey path. What the space is? Is it union of those paths? Complement in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Are those maybe knots? Something else? I don't understand what is not homotopic here.

Comment: @freakish I meant the images of the paths $f$ and $f_1\cdot f_2$, given that the paths themselves are homotopic. I see no problem with the fact that there are space-filling curves here, since they are not homeomorphisms - why would I think of orienting S^n with the path the fills it, given that even their topologies are different. At the same time, I see your point, indeed it is a good example with $S^1$. I guess then I need some other way to think, what does it geometrically mean for paths to be homotopic. Could you suggest anything along these lines, perhaps?

Comment: @Ilya paths are rarely homeomorphisms, I don't know why you consider homeomorphisms only. In fact any path $S^1\to S^1$ is homotopic to $z\mapsto z^n$ (Hopf theorem) for precisely one $n$, while these are homeomorphisms only for $n=\pm 1$. Btw your own $f_1\cdot g\cdot \overline{g}\cdot f_2$ is not a homeomorphism. But since you mentioned homeomorphisms: do you perhaps consider knots and ambient isotopy in your second drawing? This is a very specific type of homotopy, in fact all knots are even homeomorphic, but not necessarily ambient isotopic.

Comment: @LeeMosher would it be better if I've put arrows on the curves in the last pictures? Also, I would not say that referring to something as *nonsense* is polite enough to be accepted as a valuable comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me sum up what I wrote in comments.

> So how to understand what is the connection between the homotopy equivalence of topological spaces and paths they correspond to?

I think this question reveals the main flaw in your reasoning. **Spaces do not correspond to any path.** You confuse a path with its image. Path is just a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to X$. And space is a space. And indeed, two paths can be homotopic, while their images are not.

The simplest example is as follows: let $\lambda:[0,1]\to X$ be any path. Then $\lambda\cdot\overline{\lambda}$ is **always** homotopic to the constant loop, regardless of what its image is (which is equal to the image of $\lambda$). Assume furthermore that there is a surjective path $[0,1]\to X$, i.e. $X$ is a [Peano space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#The_Hahn%E2%80%93Mazurkiewicz_theorem). Does this imply that every Peano space is contractible? Of course not. $S^1$ (or any sphere) is a non-contractible Peano space.

The opposite situation is also possible, i.e. two paths have homotopic images, while they are not homotopic. For example consider $S^1$ as a subset of complex numbers of norm $1$. Then consider two loops $S^1\to S^1$, $z\mapsto z$ and $z\mapsto z^2$ (I use $S^1$ in domain instead of $[0,1]$ since loops over $[0,1]$ correspond to continuous functions over $S^1$). It is well known these are not homotopic ([Hopf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_theorem)) but their images are not only homotopic, they are literally equal (both to full $S^1$).

All in all: do not think about paths as their images. This is sometimes useful, but generally is wrong.

For me a path is a way of moving a point over a space in time. The image is not that important, because we can visit a single place multiple times, we can go backwards, etc. So "how" we move matters more, image itself is not enough. Now if $X$ is additionally locally compact Hausdorff space then a homotopy between two paths $[0,1]\times[0,1]\to X$ is the same as path $[0,1]\to C([0,1], X)$, where $C([0,1],X)$ denotes the space of all continuous functions $[0,1]\to X$ (with compact-open topology). And that's how I personally think about homotopies: it's a path but in the space of continuous functions. Sort of higher level path. Of course you have to be careful, this intuition doesn't work for non-locally compact spaces. Still, it covers lots of everyday examples (e.g. manifolds and locally finite CW complexes).

> On the pictures below $f$ and $f_1\cdot f_2$ are path homotopic, and yet the corresponding spaces are not homotopy equivalent

What exactly are those corresponding spaces? Here are my guesses (from the most probable to the least probable):

1. The space $X$ is $\mathbb{R}^3\backslash S^1$ where $S^1$ is embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$, say by adding $0$ at the last coordinate. Then we consider two greyed paths $f$ and $f_1\cdot f_2$. Indeed, their images are even homeomorphic, but these are not homotopic inside our $X$. Note the importance of $X$. If you add the missing black circle they are again homotopic, without modyfing those paths. And so being homotopic is not an internal property of paths, it heavily depends on the ambient space.
2. The space in question is the complement of union of black and grey circle. In that case indeed, two spaces can be homotopic while their complements are not. The simplest example is $X=[0,1]$, $A=\{0\}$, $B=\{\frac{1}{2}\}$. In this case $A$ and $B$ are clearly even homeomorphic, but $X\backslash A$ is not homotopy equivalent to $X\backslash B$ because the first one is connected while the second one is not.
3. The space in question are grey paths, and we actually look at them as knots, and we consider [ambient isotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_isotopy). Indeed, two spaces can be homotopic, but not ambient isotopic. In fact every two knots are even homeomorphic, because by definition, a knot is an embedding of $S^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$. I'm putting this interpretation here, since you've mentioned homeomorphisms in comments. Note that in general paths are rarely homeomorphisms, e.g. every path $S^1\to S^1$ is homotopic to $z\mapsto z^n$ for precisely one $n$ (again: Hopf theorem), but these are homeomorphisms only for $n=\pm 1$. So in a sense most paths $S^1\to S^1$ are not homeomorphisms. In fact your own $f_1\cdot g\cdot\overline{g}\cdot f_2$ path is not a homeomorphism.

Either way, you have to be precise. It is  unclear what happens in your second drawing (the first one is sort of ok). What spaces I am working with? What are those paths? What are their formulas? What $x_0$ is? And since it is different in both cases why $x_0$ matters? Finally what homotopy theory I'm working with? Once you make everything as precise as possible, I'm sure you will be able to answer your own questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in one of the comments to the OP I've replied to you that I in the last two pictures I've referred to images of $f_1$ and $f_1\cdot f_2$ as paths. Anyways, as far as I understood, thinking about homotopy of paths on the level of their images is completely wrong and may be dangerous. That's a valuable point. Does not help to get a gut feeling on which paths should be homotopic to one another, unfortunately. If you add some comments on that to your answer, I'll be extremely grateful.

Comment: @Ilya yeah, it is generally hard to deduce whether two paths are homotopic or not. I might not be able to help you in building this intuition. But note that we often care about homotopy groups only, which often can be calculated in other ways (e.g. van Kampen), not by figuring out which paths are homotopic and which are not.

Comment: This question popped up exactly when I was reading the proof of vK in Hatcher, and that made me think about the intuition about the fundamental group of $\Bbb R^3\setminus S^1$ in the beginning of the book, which he informally convinced me is $\Bbb Z$, yet I could not get around a nasty feeling about this trick that we can "unglue" two paths at the base point (to go from two grey paths $f_1, f_2$ to a single $f$ in my lowly drawings). Perhaps my impression that this intuition is given there is incorrect. Otherwise, it's unfortunate